# Javascript Increase Name array() By One

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript code which duplicates a container when the user needs to add more rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[ 
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('inlinedup');

    function duplicate() {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.id = "inlinedup" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, original.nextSibling);
    }
    //]]>  
</script>
```

My question is, how can I edit this javascript to also increase the name array by one every time this is duplicated?

Example:

```
name="prepmethod[$i]"
```

Please see the fiddle for a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/79WYA/8/

Comment: I think the `name` should stand  as it is because otherwise It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Er... you don't need to.

If you have:

```
<input type="text" name="prepmethod[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="prepmethod[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="prepmethod[]" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="prepmethod[]" value="4" />
```

Then the resulting array on the server will be `array(1,2,3,4)`. That's it. You don't have to do anything.

As a side-note, I'd suggest just setting `clone.id = "";`, unless you have a specific need to use the ID later.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking I needed to assign individual keys to each one. I'll give that a shot and let you know. Thanks